# Is there a platform I can use to do my Maths assignment?

Tags: soft-question, math-software

If one wants to do Maths assignment on the computer, how would he/she go about doing it? I want to be able to use all the mathematical symbols, matrices, formulas and whatnot- the same way mathematicians do when they publish papers.

In other words: what software do people use when they publish Maths research paper, textbook, notes, etc?

Comment: Good place to start reading about [latex](https://www.latex-project.org/)

Comment: To add, a good editor for working on LaTeX documents is Texmaker, http://www.xm1math.net/texmaker/

Answer (score 3):

[$\mathrm{\LaTeX}$](http://www.latex-project.org): search Google for many introductions.

(I have previously compiled a lot of $\mathrm{\LaTeX}$ resources [here](https://github.com/artemmavrin/learn-latex/blob/master/README.md))

Comment: plain and simple. thumbs up.

Comment: I use TexPad for OS X. its on the app store and you have to pay but it is pretty user friendly with a live updating preview of how the page will look.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the software [GNU TeXmacs](http://www.texmacs.org/) if you've never used $\LaTeX$ before. It's pretty easy to use and it's also self-explanatory.

Answer (score 1):

Another good possibility is [LyX](https://www.lyx.org) . It's a front end to LaTeX (as much as texmacs) built according to the concept "what you see is what you mean". Writing equations becomes bullet fast. It also produces a very nice LaTeX code (as opposed to texmacs) and it's fully supported and upgraded